# An error when concatenating strings with conditional operator involved on sqlce with linq

Tags: c#, linq, sql-server-ce

I'm getting the error

`There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 3,Token line offset = 60,Token in error = MAX ]`

while trying to create dynamically concatenated anonymous type string member in some linq query

```
from ...
select new
{
    //this line throws an error
    VehicleName = VB != null? (VB.Name + " " + VM.Name) : VM.Name,

    //but without it, those 2 similar lines run just fine
    VehicleName2 = VB.Name + " " + VM.Name,
    VehicleName3 = VB != null? VB.Name : VM.Name,
}
```

It's a simple joining query with mandatory VM object and optional VB. What am I missing here? I'll be glad for any hint.

edit: from what I've googled it's SQL related error, that occurs when trying to nest another query inside sume functions parameters (I suppose CONCAT would be the case here), but I can't figure it out why would linq generate such a code. It may be possible, that it's strictly associated with sqlce in 3.5 version, although i'm not sure.

Comment: I don't get any such error. Can you show the entire query you are using?

Comment: There's absolutely nothing relevant in the query, just a simple left join and I don't want to make my post messy. Both conditional operator and string concatenating operations work fine, they just don't work when used together.